# moment.js - subtract 1 day from Sunday not working as expected

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a moment object that I want to subtract 1 day from. The original date shows as `Sun Jul 15 2018 12:00:00` and I want to subtract 1 day from it so that it outputs as `Sat Jul 14 2018 12:00:00`.

This seems like it should be really easy if I use the `subtract()` function, but it's changing the date to the upcoming Saturday, not the Saturday before July 15. I'm assuming this has something to do with the week starting on July 15.

This seems to only be an issue when I'm using Sunday as my starting date. How can I make this work the way I need it to?

Here is my JS:

```
var timeFormat = 'dddd h:mma';
var originalDate = moment("sunday 12:00:00pm", timeFormat);
var previousDay = moment(originalDate).subtract(1, 'days').format(timeFormat);
var newDate = moment(previousDay+"12:00:00pm", timeFormat);

$(".openTime span").text(originalDate);
$(".newOpenTime span").text(newDate);
```

This outputs `Sun Jul 15 2018 12:00:00` as the `originalDate` and `Sat Jul 21 2018 12:00:00` as the date subtracted by 1 day. As you can see the new date is now `Sat Jul 21` for some reason.

Here's a JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/b5ev8knd/22/

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ztLsgvju/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a formatted string to create the `newDate`. The string says something like this:
'Saturday 12:00:00pm'. MomentJs has no information what Saturday you actually mean, so it just takes the next one, which is the 21st of July.

If you just use the `previousDay` moment and format it, it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/b5ev8knd/36/